# How to keep the form fields filled in case of validation error Magento 2

Tags: magento2, php

I have created a custom module for Distributor registration its having a custom form with some extra fields for registration. Distributor registration is working fine but i am not able to retain the form filed value in case there if there is server side validation error.

I have tried to followed customer registration module and form and found that Magento keeps the value in session like this.

in CreatePost.php controller

```
$this->session->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
```

and retaining the form value by bellow line of code in form.

```
<?php echo $block->escapeHtml($block->getFormData()->getCity()) ?>
```

Is there any other way i can use to keep the form filled in case of validation error ?

Comment: Please add code which you have used in controller file and block file.

Answer (score 1):

If you check Customer module in Magento 2, you will find that it is using `$block->getFormData()` function to get data.
Now when you go to `Customer\Block\Form\Register` block, you will find `getFormData` function,

```
public function getFormData()
{
    $data = $this->getData('form_data');
    if ($data === null) {
        $formData = $this->_customerSession->getCustomerFormData(true);
        $data = new \Magento\Framework\DataObject();
        if ($formData) {
            $data->addData($formData);
            $data->setCustomerData(1);
        }
        if (isset($data['region_id'])) {
            $data['region_id'] = (int)$data['region_id'];
        }
        $this->setData('form_data', $data);
    }
    return $data;
}
```

This function gets data from session you set in your controller with code

```
$this->_customerSession->setCustomerFormData($this->getRequest()->getPostValue());
```

and set it in a variable `form_data` which is used as `$block->getFormData` in phtml file. You also need to create the same function in your block to get data.

Comment: i did the same but somehow its not working. I have the value in the session but still getFormData() is showing empty error

Comment: Can you please add your controller and block file code to you question?

Comment: Some how session data in not coming in block. When i am writing this 
$objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
$session = $objectManager->create('Magento\Customer\Model\Session');
then form data is working..

Comment: Are you saving data in customer session? Can put your code for adding data to customer session